# idea for designing the following screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

[image: LoginScreen]

I know how to add the footer but how to add the header(login box) at the middle as in the screen

Comment: relativelayout with some imageviews perhaps (to fix login box)

Comment: use this property for Relative layout  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: Using idea from web development, the 'Login Box' and the background can be an image background but different screens may display them differently though. The rest like the labels and textbox can be done usimg relativelayout as Keyser suggested.

Comment: see this link http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-shared-preferences.html

Comment: if we are giving the background black then it is occupying the complete screen but in the above screen some gap is there at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use **Relative layout**
2. Use **transparent image**  for Login box
3. and more add this layout in **Dialog** will give good look to your app

Answer (score 0):

use this property for Relative layout in xml

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```